# How to remove product_list block from cache in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I need to remove the product_list block from cache
Class: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
Block: /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

I have tried these solutions:

```
public function getCacheLifetime()
{
    return null;
}
```

I have tried **$_isScopePrivate = true;** too.

Nothing seems to be working.
I need to update the product collection on category list page based upon user input, so I need to remove the block from cache. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that this is a good idea? because all pages with non cached blocks are excluded from full page caching. in your case, all category pages are excluded from full page caching. i think, you have to solve your problem with dynamic loaded content.

if you really want to disable the cache for a specific magento block, you can do it in a xml file. See [here](https://www.thecoachsmb.com/how-to-disable-the-cache-for-the-block-in-magento-2/).

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceContainer name="category.products">
         <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Hi, putting cacheable="false" will remove entire page from cache, won't it?

Comment: yes. all pages with a non cacheable block on it are excluded from full page cache.

Comment: So, this is not what I need to achieve. I just need my block out of the cache which is not working for me.

Comment: yes, but if you have just one block on a page, the whole page is excluded from full page cache. this is a magento behavior. if you can live with that, try the xml solution in my answer to exclude the block from cache.

Comment: Sorry, this solution won't work as we definitely cannot exclude entire page from FPC.